# Yii2 RestFull API - Error 404 on production with few actions onlyy

Tags: php, api, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a problem,
I created many actions for an API using Yii2.
I have met a recent problem: while everything works on localhost, when I upload on the server, the below actions return a 404 error.

I have been trying many different solution (try to create another controller) with no success

The goal of those functions is to upload/delete images.

**config/main.php**

```
      'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => require 'urls.php',
        ],
```

**config/urls.php**

```
    'POST api/controller/<id>/logo-upload' => 'controller-name/logo-upload',
    'POST api/controller/<id>/background-image-upload' => 'controller-name/background-image-upload',
    'POST api/controller/<id>/gallery-upload' => 'controller-name/update-gallery',
    'POST api/controller/<id>/delete-logo' => 'controller-name/delete-logo-image',
    'POST api/controller/<id>/delete-background' => 'controller-name/delete-background-image',
    'POST api/controller/<id>/gallery/<galleryID>/delete' => 'controller-name/delete-gallery-image',
```

Here a sample controller I created. I changed some variable names or class names but nothing that doesn't change the logic.

**controller-name.php**

```
    <?php


namespace frontend\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\filters\Cors;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\filters\ContentNegotiator;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\helpers\BaseJson;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use Yii;


class Controller extends RestController
{


    public $modelClass = 'common\models\Model';

    public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();

        unset($actions['delete'], $actions['create'], $actions['update'], $actions['index'], $actions['options']);

        return $actions;
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {

        return ArrayHelper::merge([
            [
                'class' => Cors::className(),
                'cors' => [
                    'Origin' => ['*'],
                    'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'POST'],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
                'only' => ['view', 'index', 'update'],  // in a controller
                // if in a module, use the following IDs for user actions
                // 'only' => ['user/view', 'user/index']
                'formats' => [
                    'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
                ],
                'languages' => [
                    'en',
                    'fr',
                ],
            ]
        ], parent::behaviors());
    }



    protected function verbs()
    {
        return [
            'index' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
            'view' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
            'create' => ['POST'],
            'update' => ['POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH'],
            'delete' => ['DELETE'],
        ];
    }

    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Model::findOne($id)) !== null &&
            (Yii::$app->user->identity->isAdmin() || $model->owner_id === Yii::$app->user->id)
        ) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
    public function actionLogoUpload($id)
    {
      $card = $this->findModel($id);
      $image = Image::upload($card, 'logoImageFile');
      if ($image->errors) {
        return $result = ["success"=>false, "message"=> $image->getErrors()];
      }
      if (!empty($image)) {

          $card->image_id = $image->id;
          if ($card->validate() && $card->save()) {
            $result = [
                "success"
            ];
            // }
            return $result;
          } else {
            return $result = ["success"=>false, "message"=> $card->getErrors()];
          }
      }

    }

}
```

**Edit**

Okay removing Content-type:multipart/form date in the header makes the route working, but obviously the code doesn't work since no file is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay turned out there was an extra space in the request. The code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely with your server configuration. You have to configure your server to rewrite unknown paths to your `index.php` script.

For example, when I've used yii2 with apache, I have the following `web/.htaccess` file:

```
# use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

# ...other settings...
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Of course, a lot of the details are dependent on your hosting and server configuration (e.g. are `.htaccess` files allowed). Yii's docs have more information on configuring different web servers [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation#configuring-web-servers).

Comment: I checked and sadly the server configuration is ok but thank you :)
By the way there are over 50 actions for the api and only those listed above don't work.